# cisco vpn and on demand routing

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, cisco-vpn

We need to connect to a partner via a Cisco VPN from one of our internal servers.

This server is already configured for demand dial routing to a different partner, using windows RRAS.

The partner provided us the group authentication credentials and the regular logon credentials.

Basically, I need to configure it so that when this server needs to access a specific host it will automatically establish the vpn connection and route that specific traffic to them.

How can I do this?

I've installed the Cisco VPN Client (5.0.07.0440) on the server and I can open it up and connect.  However, I'm stuck on how to configure this to automatically happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demand dial routing won't be able to connect via the Cisco VPN client.  You'll have to have what ever automated process that needs to actually connect to the remote site start the Cisco VPN software.  You can configure the Cisco software to save the password (assuming that the remote router supports this) and configure the Cisco software to automatically VPN in when it starts.  Then you just need to kill the Cisco software after your process is complete.